# jQuery slice all keys from multidimensional associative array

Tags: jquery, arrays, key, slice

**UPDATED QUESTION**

Here is the console output of an array (dataSet) in jQuery:

```
[
    {
        "Alias_0":"Toto",
        "Address_1":"Here",
        "Location_0":"Bombay"
    },
    {
        "Alias_0":"Tata",
        "Address_1":"There",
        "Location_0":"Berlin"
    },
    {
        "Alias_0":"Tutu",
        "Address_1":"Somewhere",
        "Location_0":"Brussels"
    }
]
```

Here is how I would like to transform it:

```
[
    {
        "Alias":"Toto",
        "Address":"Here",
        "Location":"Bombay"
    },
    {
        "Alias":"Tata",
        "Address":"There",
        "Location":"Berlin"
    },
    {
        "Alias":"Tutu",
        "Address":"Somewhere",
        "Location":"Brussels"
    }
]
```

Here is my attempt:

```
var dataSet = [
    {"Alias_0": "Toto", "Address_1": "Here",      "Location_0": "Bombay"},
    {"Alias_0": "Tata", "Address_1": "There",     "Location_0": "Berlin"},
    {"Alias_0": "Tutu", "Address_1": "Somewhere", "Location_0": "Brussels"}
];

var result=[];

$.each(dataSet, function(key1,value1){
    result[key1] = new Array();
    $.each(dataSet[key1], function(key2,value2){
        key2=key2.slice(0,-2);          
        result[key1][key2] = new Array();
        result[key1][key2] = value2;
    })
})

console.log(result)
```

Here is what I get:

```
[
    [],
    [],
    []
]
```

What is the problem here?
Keys and values, when output in the console, show the expected data. But the "result" array doesn't include them. 
Moreover, the new array format is not good ([] instead of {})

FYI: I would have much preferred to just strip the last characters of the keys from the **original** array but as I was unable to do that, I'm trying to create a second array from the original array. But if it is possible to just directly transform the original array without creating a second one, that would be ideal.

All in all, this seems overly complicated to just strip two characters from each key of an array. There must be a simpler way (straight function?)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
var data = [{"black_0": "1", "red_1": "2", "blue_1": "3"}];

var result = Object.keys(data[0]).reduce(function(a, e) {
    a[0][e.replace(/_[01]/, '')] = data[0][e];
    return a;
}, [{}]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you gaetanoM. It works but now I only have one row in my array.
This array feeds a table and with your script, that table has one row only.
And if I cut all the [0] indexes in your script, then it doesn't work.

Comment: @BachirMessaouri Can you update the question adding a **data** array example? Thanks

Comment: See the updated question. Basically it's what you have but with many entries.
FYI: I don't need to differentiate the "_0" and "_1". I just need to blindly slice the two last characters of each and every key. It will always be "_0" or " _1" anyway.
Thank you.

Comment: That's not the update you had in mind? If you meant something else, juste let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it.

```
var dataSet = [
    {"Alias_0": "Toto", "Address_1": "Here",      "Location_0": "Bombay"},
    {"Alias_0": "Tata", "Address_1": "There",     "Location_0": "Berlin"},
    {"Alias_0": "Tutu", "Address_8": "Somewhere", "Location_0": "Brussels"}
];

var sliced_dataSet=[];

for(var i=0;i<dataSet.length;i++){
    var obj={};
    Object.keys(dataSet[i]).forEach(function(key){
        var k = key.substring(0,key.length-2);
        obj[k] = dataSet[i][key];
    });
    sliced_dataSet.push(obj);
}

console.log(arr)
```